# Custom exceptions in Elasticsearch Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, settings, nest, custom-exceptions

In the documentation it’s possible to define custom exceptions via **ConnectionConfiguration** as said [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/errors.html):

```
var settings = new ConnectionConfiguration()
    .SetConnectionStatusHandler(r=> {
        if (r.HttpStatusCode == 403)
           throw new MyApplicationNotLoggedInException();
        });
```

But **ConnectionConfiguration** is the way of setting up the low level API. Currently I use only Nest and my only option is to redefine **ConnectionSettings** where my only option is *.ThrowExceptions(bool)*. Is there any option to use the low level api settings in Nest?

Comment: You're looking at a very old version of the documentation. Take a look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/logging-with-on-request-completed.html `OnRequestCompleted()` is the method to use

Comment: I can't catch the exception thrown inside the OnRequestCompleted. It doesn't help at all.

Comment: Can you update the question to show how you are using the OnRequestCompleted to catch the exception that is thrown? There is an example of custom exceptions at the end of the his Getting Started Guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/elasticsearch-net-getting-started.html